# Django: non-nullable field without a default

Tags: python, django, django-models, null, field

In Django I use `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` on the following models.py file:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    comment1 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    #comment2 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

After this successful initialization, I changed **models.py** to (I just uncomment the new model field which is basically a copy of the other model field):

```
class Family(models.Model):
    comment1 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    comment2 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Now when I try to `makemigrations` again I get the following **error**:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'comment' to family without
>   a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate
>   existing rows).
>
> Please select a fix:
>
> 1) Provide a one-off default now
>   (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>
> 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py Select an option:

Why didn't I get this error upon intialization in the first place?

Comment: Because you were creating the table from scratch. Now, as the error explicitly says, the database needs something to populate existing rows.

Comment: but there are no existing rows. just like when I initialized!

Comment: ok I think I got it. although there are no existing rows, in principle there could be. and then Django wouldn't know how to save "comment2" of existing rows since it cannot save them as null and it doesn't have a value for those. at the first migration Django knew: I'm creating a table, hence no previous data, hence null=False + no default value is okay. The user will only be able to save objects with a value for "comment1" but that's his problem.

Comment: It's not even "in principle". Migrations aren't just for your current development database, they're for production too; if you deployed version 1, your prod database could have content even though your dev one doesn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's what "in principle" means - in principle, there may or may not be data on a given system, so complain regardless of current data in table.

Answer (score 3):

Others are right. you should set a default value for that field.
but there is a a trick that you can solve this. but it is not a good way... only if you have no choice. 
1. comment all of your table 
2. run `makemigrations` and `migrate` 
3. uncomment your table
4.2. run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again

Comment: It helped me. Thanks. But you said it is not a good way. So do we have another choice other than this?

Answer (score 3):

`image1=models.ImageField(upload_to='app/image12',help_text="hi", null=True)`

That is, set `null= True'`in the field.

It happens when you change your model after stored database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it non nullable without default.
you have to provide value for the same field when you create migration file. thats why it asks for the option. type "1" in terminal while python manage.py makemigrations and then provide a value for the field for previously saved row(if any).

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a same issue, in my case:

Focus on the alert:

> ...non-nullable field 'comment' to family...

- model: Family
- field: comment

Just add one more attr in the field comment of the model family:

```
default=''
```

Comment: The Question Says "non-nullable field **_without a default_**"

Answer (score 0):

Just select option `1`. Then set a default.
It will create a migration script with the property `preserve_default=False` which means the default is used only for the migration. It will not affect the default settings in the database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield

Answer (score -1):

You can add this: `default=None` or `default="something"`
or `add null=True`, `blank=True`.